# How to fade html element out and the fade new element in it's place

Tags: html, css

I have a number of questions:

```
<div id='q1'>question...</div>
<div id='q2'>question...</div>
<div id='q3'>question...</div>
etc...
```

Only one question div should be visible at any time.

I want each question to fade out and the new question fade in exactly where the previous question was.

I am using this CSS for the fade transitions:

```
.fade-out {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-name: fadeOutOpacity;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}


.fade-in {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-name: fadeInOpacity;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    transition-delay: 4s;
}

@keyframes fadeInOpacity {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeOutOpacity {
    0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
```

But when the second question has the `fade-in` css class applied, it makes the first question jump up before it's faded out.

Ideally, I'd like the first question to fade out and the become `display: none;`

But I am struggling to get it to work.

**Questions**

1. How can I get the first question to 'fade-out' and the second 'fade-in' in it's place?

**N.B** I'd rather a pure CSS solution than a Jquery solution if possible...

Answer (score 3):

Like in most pure CSS solutions you might want to utilize input elements. Here I am using radio types with labels inside to reach the next question.

As you are only changing opacity you might want to use a transition instead of an animation. I am using the shorthand here which can be expanded like this:

```
transition: property-name duration easing delay;
```

Here is a working example:

```css
/* wrapper to hold absolute positioned children */
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

/* hide actual radio buttons */
.wrapper input {
  display: none
}

.question {
  /* float above each other */
  position: absolute;
  /* transparency by default */
  opacity: 0;
  /* fade out without delay */
  transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
}

input:checked + .question {
  /* always put current question first */
  z-index: 1;
  /* fade in with delay */
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s ease-in 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input id="question-1" type="radio" name="question" checked>
  <div class="question">
    <p>Question 1</p>
    <label for="question-2">next</label>
  </div>

  <input id="question-2" type="radio" name="question">
  <div class="question">
    <p>Question 2</p>
    <label for="question-3">next</label>
  </div>

  <input id="question-3" type="radio" name="question">
  <div class="question">
    <p>Question 3</p>
    <label for="question-1">start over</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily without needing an `animation` Instead you only need `transition`.

Run this code snippet example:

```js
function doNext() {
  let el = document.querySelector('.questions [showing]');
  el.removeAttribute('showing');
  let temp = el.nextElementSibling;
  if (temp === null) {
    temp = el.parentElement.firstElementChild;
  }
  
  temp.setAttribute('showing', '');
}

const btn = document.querySelector('#next');
btn.addEventListener('click', doNext);
```

```css
.questions {
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
}

.fader {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.fader[showing] {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1s ease 0.75s;
}
```

```html
<div class="questions">
  <div id='q1' class="fader" showing>question...1</div>
  <div id='q2' class="fader">question...2</div>
  <div id='q3' class="fader">question...3</div>
  <div id='q4' class="fader">question...4</div>
</div>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

When the attribute `showing` is removed then the `opacity` of the question goes from 1 to 0 over 1 seconds. When the attribute `showing` is added then the element waits for 0.75 seconds and then changes `opacity` from 0 to 1 over 1 seconds.

The JavaScript I have added simple allows the changing of which element has the attribute `showing`. Your code would need to do something similar to change which question is showing.

*I set the position of each question to `absolute` with `top` set to `0` so that all questions show in the same place. **BUT** doing this requires that you know that maximum size of your questions so the container can be set to the correct height.*

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample:

```css
.fade-out { 
    opacity: 0; 
    animation-name: fadeOutOpacity; 
    animation-iteration-count: 1; 
    animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
    animation-duration: 2s;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
} 

.fade-in { 
    opacity: 1; 
    animation-name: fadeInOpacity; 
    animation-iteration-count: 1; 
    animation-timing-function: ease-in; 
    animation-duration: 4s; 
    animation-delay: 0s;
} 

@keyframes fadeInOpacity { 
    0% { 
        opacity: 0; 
    } 
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% { 
        opacity: 1; 
    } 
} 

@keyframes fadeOutOpacity { 
    0% { 
        opacity: 1; 
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
    } 
    100% { 
        opacity: 0; 
    } 
}
```

```html
<div id='q1' class="fade-out">question...1</div>
<div id='q2' class="fade-in">question...2</div>
```

Comment: You could also set `animation-duration: 2s;` and `animation-delay: 2s;` in your `.fade-in` block

Comment: Thanks a lot @Intervalia

Comment: @AdnanToky Could you turn this into a working demo (StackSnippet)? *(Edit question, press Ctrl+M, add code to appropriate area)*

Comment: Click on the button "Run code snippet" it runs just fine